# Passing CLLocation to the next view using segue

Tags: ios, swift, segue, core-location

I get the current location in the main view, and want to pass this location object to the next view using segue. The segue might be a normal "Show" type of new view page, or an "Embed" type of subview. Here is my script:

```
import UIKit
import CoreLocation

class ViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    var clmanager: CLLocationManager!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        clmanager = CLLocationManager()
        clmanager.delegate = self
        clmanager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        clmanager.startUpdatingLocation()
    }

    var location : CLLocation?
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        location = locations[0]
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if (segue.identifier == "showSegue") { // This part is totally OK
            let dest = segue.destination as! ShowViewController
            dest.object = self.location
        }

        if (segue.identifier == "embedSegue") { // This part is not OK!!!
            let dest = segue.destination as! EmbedViewController
            dest.object = self.location
        }
    }
}
```

I think the difference between the "Show" and "Embed" type is that the "Show" type is **manually** activated by users, but the "Embed" type is **immediately** activated when the main view is loaded. At that time, the location is not still available yet.

How to make the "Embed" part successful? **I wish if the updated location is available, the embedded subview should be updated automatically**.

Comment: You need to define "location" at the class level like "clmanager".

Comment: You wrote: `let location = locations[0]`. What do you think the scope of `location` is? does it *exist* outside the `func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
` function?! Apparently not

Comment: Or just use `clmanager.location`. No need to save off the location in `didUpdateLocations`.

Comment: your location object have declare in the local scope co you need to use that so need to declare in global scope.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I've changed my question. The previous question might not show my problems

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add this in your detailViewController

```
var location : CLLocation?
```

//Declare a location variable in first class..

```
 var location : CLLocation?
    // Get location
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
       // Ammendment here
        location = locations[0]

    print(location)
}

// Pass to the next view
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if (segue.identifier == "thisSegue") {
        let dest = segue.destination as! DetailViewController
        dest.location = self.location
    }
}
```

you need to make sure that show perform segue when there is a location available in didUpdateLocations Method

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I've updated my question. The previous question might not show my problems

Comment: are you adding embedded segue using code or Storyboard?

Answer (score 0):

Make a variable that can be accessed in any part of the class and store your location in it. Using that variable for the segue wouldn't be a problem after that.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I've updated my question. The previous question might not show my problems